# Asp.Net Core Razor pages, session variable is not accessible from other views/razor models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-variables, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am saving session variable in login page,

```
Guid sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();

HttpContext.Session.SetString("sessionId",sessionId.ToString());
Response.Cookies.Append("sessionId", sessionId.ToString());
```

Now I access this variable like this:

```
string sessionId = Request.Cookies["sessionId"];            

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId) && sessionId.Equals(HttpContext.Session.GetString("sessionId")))
{
    return RedirectToPage("/LoggedIn/Index");
}

return Page();
```

This code I use on the same razor page (login page) in which session Id is declared, however if I use the above code in any other razor view page, I cannot access this session variable. It is only accessible on the same page it was saved.

What can I possibly be doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you add app.UseSession() to your Startup.cs Configure method?

Comment: @ibrahimozgon Yes I added that as well as services.AddSession but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you add services.AddMemoryCache() ?

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes I did add it

Comment: Have you tried that codes in a new razor pages application ? I would suggest check other codes which may affect the session .

Comment: Have you tried adding `app.UseSession()` before `app.UseMvc()` in your Startup.cs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I had to change the entire context of my previous comment. Here is the "Correct Answer".**

Just make sure you have checked below steps:

1. `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()` memory is configured for caching.
2. `services.AddSession()` you've configured session.
3. Here's where people make the mistake  `app.UseSession()` must be called after `app.UseCookiePolicy()` and before `app.UseMvc()` .

**Note that a `RedirectToPage()`call does not affect/change session variables at all. **

These steps look basic but actually step 3 is the answer you're looking for. Your code looks absolutely fine.

Here's the Middleware Ordering as outlined by Rick Anderson and Steve Smith
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#order

Sometimes the problem might be caused by `CheckConsentNeeded = context => true` being set to true when you configure your CookiePolicyOptions. Just set it to false if you have `<CookiePolicyOptions>` configured. If you want to leave it as true you must then configure `cookie` and set `Cookie.IsEssential = true;` Then the session will survive any redirect action.

Comment: +1 for the CheckConsentNeeded = context => true.  I had everything else setup correctly but Session would not survive a RedirectToPage until I set that to false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `Context.Session.TryGetValue` as opposed to `HttpContext` in .Net Core

You will need the `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` namespace in your view

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your HttpContextAccessor and Session in Startup.cs first.

```
//ConfigureServices
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

and

```
//Configure
app.UseSession();
```

Then you can access HttpContext on IHttpContextAccessor anywhere. I've set session in Index action.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("session1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        return View();
    }
}
```

And accessed it in About.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
<h1>Session Value:</h1>
<p>@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("session1")</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't working either, tried it using in Razor page but the value resulted was null/nothing

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't change your session or cookie value somewhere else?

Comment: No I didn't, can you show me the same code for a Razor page ? I see you are trying to explain via MVC concept but I am not using any controllers at the moment, only Razor views and Razor models which are built in

Comment: I'm not sure how to use in razor pages but it can be like this:

`@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("session1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

You need storage for session data. You can use the memory cache for most applications. You enable it with `services.AddMemoryCache()` in the ConfigureServices method. See  https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/session-state

Comment: That is the tutorial that I followed till now but couldn't access session variable from other razor pages except the one I saved that variable in. I am already using services.AddMemoryCache() in startup file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using Session Variable for security reasons. However, if you need to store data between sessions but ViewBag is not sufficient, I recommend building your own based on the logged in user and store it in the database:

```
data.SetGUIDsessionVariable(User.Identity.Name, ThingToStore);

string ThingThatWasStored = data.GetGUIDsessionVariable(User.Identity.Name);
```

If you cannot use the login name, then use a unique "session variable" GUID instead of the User Identity Name. Either way is fine:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid()
```

The way Session variables work is not secure and (quite frankly) is made deliberately (and excessively) difficult and impractical in Razor. Query strings are not secure either. But storing them in the database based on an internal username or random GUID is quite secure.

You're welcome. Writing the code for SetGUIDsessionVariable() ad GetGUIDsessionVariable() is left up to you. I did it in SQL Server but Entity Framework should be possible also.